# Hide on click Outside of element angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I created a side menu for my vertical navigation, so I toggle the side-menu on click. I need to close that menu on click anywhere outside that menu. I tried installing :

https://github.com/chliebel/angular2-click-outside

But it doesn't work for some reason, I run `npm install`, add the

```
(clickOutside)="close()"
```

to my component or side menu wrapper and nothing happens.

Any help please? The directive code:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
    constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    @Output()
    public clickOutside = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
    public onClick(event: MouseEvent, targetElement: HTMLElement): void {
        if (!targetElement) {
            return;
        }

        const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
        if (!clickedInside) {
            this.clickOutside.emit(event);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I have not used that library but as a workaround without the library what you can do is attach a click event handler on your SideBar component and toggle the showFlag of sidebar. And in the sidebar can have *ngIf with that flag type like

```
@Component({
  host: {
   '(document:click)': 'onClick($event)',
  },
})
class SidebarComponent() {
  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) { }

  onClick(event) {
  if (!this._el.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) // similar checks
   resetShowFlagSidebar();
 }
}
```

Comment: I have to use HostListener(), cant use host at  Component, so should I use it like this:

HostListener('document:click') click(event: Event)

then do the if loop, but what do I do with resetShowFlagSidebar(), i mean, im not using it anywhere

Comment: resetShowFlagSidebar() is just for name sake a function which will toggle the flag attached to your sidebar. Lets say the html is like <sidebar *ngIf="showFlag"></sidebar> Then you can toggle the flag value accordingly to hide and show sidebar..or [hidden] collapse whatever you want.

Comment: this is what I tried to do:

@HostListener('document: click') click(event) {
    if (!this._el.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
      this.hideMenu();
    }
  }

Comment: But why you are doing inside directive you need to do it inside the component directly, so that that particular component goes to the function accordingly, instead of going via the directive and its event emitter. Try once in component and then see if it works.

Comment: Im not doing it in directive, i am doing this inside the component. The side menu is a child component, so I used Output() to emit(false) state of menu, like I usually do when doing show/hide on click.

Answer (score 3):

That package doesn't support Angular 4. There is an updated package https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-click-outside for Angular 4+.

I can confirm that package works in Angular 5.