# Close on Click outside Angular 2 (4)

Tags: angular, angular2-template

recently I posted similar question but I couldn't make it work, so I'll reference it here and ask for help again since I haven't been able to do it.

Question: [Hide on click Outside of element angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44043746/hide-on-click-outside-of-element-angular-4)

So, I need to do the following: I have a side menu and on click of one list item in that menu, I open another sidebar menu (it's not a dropdown), and I need to close it when clicking anywhere but on that new side menu.

My component structure is the following: Layout component > Sidebar Component > Small Menu Component.

So I open small menu on click inside sidebar component. I have tried: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-click-outside

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-click-outside

They dont seem to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I've actually dealt with this but only with a single dropdown but I feel like it would be similar to what you are looking for.

In your component/directive

```
constructor() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.offClickHandler.bind(this));
}

offClickHandler(event:any) {
    if (!event.target.closest(".select-options") && !event.target.closest(".select-input")) { 
        // do whatever you want here
    }
}
```

This will check to see if there was a click close to but not in the div/dropdown that is open. Then the code inside of the offClickHandler would execute. So just set the classes inside the offClickHandler to be the side menu that you want to close when clicking away and then hide it inside of the if statement.

Comment: I've tried this but its not working :/